# Convert a csv string to a table in csv

Tags: kdb

If we have a file containing csv then we can read it using 0:
say, we have a file x.csv on the disk then converting it to a table is easy as below

```
("SFJ";enlist",")0:`:/x.csv
```

But, how can we covert a csv string to table?
string:

```
"sym,px,vol
GG,10.2,100
AA,11.2,1000"
```

Expected output: table

```
sym px  vol
"GG"    10.2    100
"AA"    11.2    1000
```

Comment: Convert a CSV string to a table in CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you needed to programmatically get to Eliot's `s` from one big string csv there are a few options depending on the format of the csv string.

```
// \n delimited 
s:` vs "sym,px,vol\nGG,10.2,100\nAA,11.2,1000"

// if you know the row and col count. 
s:3 3#"," vs "sym,px,vol,GG,10.2,100,AA,11.2,1000"

// if you just know the col count
s:"sym,px,vol,GG,10.2,100,AA,11.2,1000"
f:{[str;noCol]
    str:"," vs str;   
    noRow:`long$(count str)%noCol;
    (noRow, noCol)#str
}
f[s;3]
```

All three output this ("sym,px,vol";"GG,10.2,100";"AA,11.2,1000")

Answer (score 3):

A string can be passed in using [0:](https://code.kx.com//v2/ref/file-text/) instead of a file handle, and the table will be created as normal:

```
q)s:("sym,px,vol";"GG,10.2,100";"AA,11.2,1000")
q)s
"sym,px,vol"
"GG,10.2,100"
"AA,11.2,1000"
q)("SFJ";enlist",")0:s
sym px   vol
-------------
GG  10.2 100
AA  11.2 1000
```